# Getting the index (x,y) of a char in a "2D" list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this working function `circuitFind` that I really don't find nice because I feel there is a better and simpler way to accomplish what it does.

```
circuitFind :: Circuit -> Tile -> Maybe Position
circuitFind c t = unpack . find (\ p -> fst p /= Nothing) . enumerate . map findTile $ c
    where findTile = findIndex (==t)
          enumerate = flip zip [0..]
          unpack a = case a of 
             Just (Just x, y) -> Just (x,y) 
             _ -> Nothing
```

Basically, the function works like this: (ie: we search for the char '3')

```
["1stline", "2ndline", "3rdline"]
              | 
        map findTile '3'
              | 
              v

[Nothing, Nothing, Just 0]
              |
          enumerate
              |
              v

[(Nothing, 0), (Nothing, 1), (Just 0, 2)]
              |
       find (\ p -> fst p /= Nothing) 
              |
              v

      Just (Just 0, 2)
              |
           unpack
              |
              v 

     ––  Just (0,2) ––
```

Is there a better way to make this function more readable/shorter/... ?

---

All the relevant code here:

```
import Data.List

type Vec2D = (Int, Int)
type Position = Vec2D
type Circuit = [[Tile]]
type Tile = Char

basicCircuit :: Circuit
basicCircuit = ["------------",
                "-b        e-",
                "------------"]

circuitFind :: Circuit -> Tile -> Maybe Position
circuitFind c t = unpack . find (\ p -> fst p /= Nothing) . enumerate . map findTile $ c
    where findTile = findIndex (==t)
          enumerate = flip zip [0..]
          unpack a = case a of 
             Just (Just x, y) -> Just (x,y) 
             _ -> Nothing
```

Some tests to illustrate the usage:

```
Main> circuitFind basicCircuit 'e'
Just (10,1)
Main> circuitFind basicCircuit 'o'
Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm rusty with Haskell, there may be a cleaner way to do this.

Code review: your code looks fine to my eyes, it's just that `circuitFind` is overly complex, as you suspected. Also note that `findIndex (==t)` can be written as `elemIndex t` ([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-List.html#elemIndex)).

> "Let us see whether we could, by chance, conceive some other general
>   problem that contains the original problem and is easier to solve." –
>   Leibnitz.

We start by solving the more general problem of finding all indices of `t` in `c`.

Let's look at the skeleton of our solution.

```
[ (x,y) | ??? ]
```

We can get `y` using `zip [0..]` as you have done.

```
[ (x,y) | (y,line) <- zip [0..] c, ??? ]
```

Now we can find `x` using `elemIndices`.

```
[ (x,y) | (y,line) <- zip [0..] c, x <- elemIndices t line ]
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation, and `Data.Maybe`, we get our solution

```
circuitFind :: Circuit -> Tile -> Maybe Position
circuitFind c t = listToMaybe [ (x,y) | (y,line) <- zip [0..] c, x <- elemIndices t line ]
```

Comment: I'll remember to use list comprehension the next time I have to do some filtering/processing, it really feels like the right tool for this purpose !